# ERROR ng.cmd run app:build:production exited with exit code 127

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I tried to build my project with CMD:

```
ionic build --prod
```

but I have this error:

[image]

Comment: did you tried to install that missing plugin ? 'proposal-numeric-separator' ?

Comment: thx bro. i just tried run this in cmd: npm i @babel/compat-data@7.8.0